# When does PHP triggers the garbage collector?

Tags: php, garbage-collection

I know the copy-on-write and reference count used by PHP, but I don't know when the garbage collector is naturally trigged.

I mean, after a variable has its reference count 0, does the GC cleans it after a method/function ends? Does it does the cleaning after a loop ends?

Well, hope the question is clear enough.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php

Comment: Good question. I ran a test a while back where i populated a variable with arbitrary data then lost the reference.  I did this in a loop a few million times but it still ran out of memory...

Answer (score 0):

<s>You can 'configure' when the garbage collector runs is via the configuration values [`session.gc-maxlifetime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime), [`session.gc-probability`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability), and [`session.gc-divisor`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-divisor).</s> (Comment from RaggaMuffin-420: These only affect the cleanup of old sessions).

You can call [`gc_collect_cycles()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php) to force garbage collection at any particular instance, but is generally looked at as a code smell (code you develop should not in general rely on whether or not the garbage collector has already run).

Comment: session.gc-* settings are for when PHP cleans the tmp Session files, pretty sure they have nothing to do with variable memory allocation.